# Collection view : stuck with implementing the reload function

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

The collection view must be reloaded after values are modified (see solvedButtonPushed function). The line `self.collectionView.reloadData()`generates the error : "Reference to member 'reloadData' cannot be resolved without a contextual type".
Can you help me writing it the right way ?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    var mySudoku = Sudoku()
    let reuseIdentifier = "sudokuCell"
    
    @IBAction func solveButtonPushed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        /*
         Values to be dislayed in the collectionView are stored in mySudoku.sudoTab.
         They are correctly displayed at program start.
         mySudoku.sudoTab is modified when the solve button is pushed.
         I did not succeed in implementing the reloadData function :
         "Reference to member 'reloadData' cannot be resolved without a contextual type"
         */
        let r = mySudoku.solve(p: mySudoku)
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
        switch r {
            case .solved :
            print("Problem solved")
            case .erroneous :
            print("Error in problem definition")
            case.notEnoughInfoToSolve :
                print("Error in problem definition")
            case .notYetSolved :
                print("Not yet solved (should not occur !")
            }
        } // end solve()
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        mySudoku.sudoTab = getProblem(nb: 81)
        //self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    
    
 
    // MARK: - UICollectionViewDataSource protocol -
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView : UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int { return 81 }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView : UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell =  collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! SudokuCollectionViewCell
        let line = indexPath.row/9
        let column = indexPath.row%9
        cell.sudokuLabel.text = String(mySudoku.sudoTab[line][column] == 0 ? "": String(mySudoku.sudoTab[line][column]))
        cell.backgroundColor = (line/3+column/3)%2 == 0 ? UIColor.white : UIColor.lightGray
        return cell
        }
    
    // MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegate protocol -
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView : UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")
        let currentValue = mySudoku.sudoTab[indexPath.item/9][indexPath.item%9]
        let newValue = (currentValue+1)%10
        mySudoku.sudoTab[indexPath.row/9][indexPath.row%9] = newValue
        print(currentValue, newValue, indexPath.row/9, indexPath.row%9)
        collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't see an IBOutlet object for the collection guy.

Comment: OOPS, forgot it ! Many thanks for your help.